# Groovy type cast and delegates

Tags: groovy

When I have a simple class hierarchy I correctly get an exception:

```
groovy:000> class Parent {}
===> true
groovy:000> class Child1 extends Parent {}
===> true
groovy:000> class Child2 extends Parent {}
===> true
groovy:000> Child1 c = new Child2()
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
Cannot cast object 'Child2@74bada02' with class 'Child2' to class 'Child1'
```

But if I have a delegate to a Map then no cast exception.

```
groovy:000> class Parent {@Delegate private Map wrappedMap; 
                          Parent(Map m) { wrappedMap = m } }
===> true
groovy:000> class Child1 extends Parent { Child1(Map m) { super(m) } }
===> true
groovy:000> class Child2 extends Parent { Child2(Map m) { super(m) } }
===> true
groovy:000> Child1 c = new Child2([:])
===> [:]
```

If I delegate to an Integer then the exception returns:

```
groovy:000> class Parent {@Delegate private Integer i; 
                          Parent(Integer iparam) { i = iparam } }
===> true
groovy:000> class Child1 extends Parent { Child1(Integer iparam) { super(iparam) } }
===> true
groovy:000> class Child2 extends Parent { Child2(Integer iparam) { super(iparam) } }
===> true
groovy:000> Child1 c = new Child2(3)
ERROR org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException:
Cannot cast object 'Child2@232a7d73' with class 'Child2' to class 'Child1'
```

What (if anything) can I do to get the cast exception even with a delegated Map?

thanks